# How to replace a value in a matrix corresponding to another matrix with some additional limitation?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix, replace

For example, this is my input matrix

```
a = [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],['1', 
'2', '3', '4', '5', '6']]
b = [[(1, 0.044), (2, 0.042)], [(4, 0.18), (6, 0.023)], [(4, 0.03), (5, 
0.023)]]
```

And I want to get

```
c= [[0.044, 0.042, 0, 0, 0, 0][0, 0, 0, 0.18, 0, 0.023][0, 0, 0, 0.03,0.023, 
0]]
```

The matrix a[0] with b[0] if the first value in b[0] == a[0], then replace the value in a with the second value in b and so on.

And I try to code like this:

```
bnn = dict(chain.from_iterable(b))
for i in a:
for ii in i:
    c = [bnn.get(i, 0) for i in map(int, ii)]
    print(c)
```

but it shows up :

```
[0.044]
[0.042]
[0]
[0.03]
[0.023]
[0.023]
[0.044]
[0.042]
[0]
[0.03]
[0.023]
[0.023]
[0.044]
[0.042]
[0]
[0.03]
[0.023]
[0.023]
```

How should I code for this?

Comment: Please post your attempts first.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use `map`, list comprehension, and dictionary with `get`:

```
c = []
for n, i in enumerate(a):
    c.append([dict(b[n]).get(i, 0) for i in map(int, a[n])])
c
```

Output:

```
[[0.044, 0.042, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0.18, 0, 0.023],
 [0, 0, 0, 0.03, 0.023, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A `numpy` solution using broadcasting, assuming `a` is just to 'show' places.

```
key,val = np.array(b).T
key = key.astype(int)-1 # -1 because in Python first place is at index 0.
res = zeros_like(a,dtype=val.dtype)
res[range(len(a)),key] = val
```

Output :

```
[[ 0.044  0.042  0.     0.     0.     0.   ]
 [ 0.     0.     0.     0.18   0.     0.023]
 [ 0.     0.     0.     0.03   0.023  0.   ]]
```